# How to Display contents from controller to full calendar bootstrap in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, calendar

I need to display json content data from controller to full calendar in php ,

Here is my controller

```
function Test_Function()
    {

$data = "{"Results":{"Results":[{"Title":"Mr","Name":"xxxxx","Date":"2016-06-04T00:00:00","Data":"Birthday","email":"sasa@asfda.com","Telephone":1234567890},{"Title":"Mr","Name":"yyyyy","Date":"2016-06-05T00:00:00","Data":"Birthday","email":"qwee@rrrrr.com","Telephone":7412589630},{"Title":"Mrs","Name":"zzzzzzz","Date":"2016-06-07T00:00:00","Data":"Anniversary","email":"asdaf@qwe.com","Telephone":1234567890}]}}"; 
  echo $data;
 }
```

I need to display Name, Data, Email and phone number in the date provided in full calander

Here is the part of full calendar

```
 var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  buttonText: {
    today: 'today',
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
  },
  //Random default events
  events: [
    {
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1),
      backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
      borderColor: "#f56954" //red
    },
    {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
      backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
      borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
      borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
    },
    {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
      borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
    },
    {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
      borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
    },
    {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
      borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
    }
  ],
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
  drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
```

Comment: I don't really see what your question is. How can we help you?

Comment: I need to display Name, Data, Email and phone number in the date provided in full calander